# XmlSerialization for custom type in WCF service

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

I'm newbie in WCF. I developed a WCF service and client for it. The service methods will retrieve custom data which uses custom XML serializer. I've read, in this case, contract methods should be marked with `[XmlSerializerFormat]`:

```
[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface ITSService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    ProtocolDocument GetReferenceData(string referenceType, SerializableDictionary<string, string> args);
```

`ProtocolDocument` implements `IXmlSerializable`:

```
[XmlRoot("protocol", Namespace = Protocol30Namespace)]
[Type(Name = "protocol", Namespace = Protocol30Namespace)]
public class ProtocolDocument : ProtocolElement, ICloneable, IXmlSerializable
```

VS 2010 chooses `wsHttpBinding` by default. I don't need in security, so I turned it off.

Here is the service configuration:

```
<services>
   <service name="MyNamespace.TSService" 
            behaviorConfiguration="MyNamespace.TSServiceBehavior">
      <host>
         <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:51944/TSService.svc" />
         </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint 
          address="" 
          binding="wsHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="nonSecurityWSHttpBinding"
          contract="MyNamespace.ITSService">
         <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
         </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint 
          address="mex" 
          binding="mexHttpBinding" 
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
   </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyNamespace.TSServiceBehavior">
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
   <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="nonSecurityWSHttpBinding">
         <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
         </security>
      </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Then I generated the client for this service, but the result could not be deserialized. Fiddler says SOAP wrapped serialized data into `GetReferenceDataResult` and `GetReferenceDataResponse`:

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/ITourSystemService/GetReferenceDataResponse</a:Action>
    <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:3d7f6dc0-4961-4bc5-b1fc-c9997af9fbd4</a:RelatesTo>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetReferenceDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetReferenceDataResult>
          <header version="3.0" language="Russian"/>
          <references/>
      </GetReferenceDataResult>
    </GetReferenceDataResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But the root element is missing! What should I do?

PS Serialization impl:

```
 void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    var serializer = new ProtocolDocumentXmlSerializer();
    serializer.Deserialize(this, reader);
}

void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    //
    // Serialize everything except the root element, because it was already written by .NET XML-serialization mechanism
    var xmlSerializationFlags = XmlSerializationFlags.All & ~XmlSerializationFlags.IncludeRootElement;

    var serializer = new ProtocolDocumentXmlSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(this, writer, xmlSerializationFlags);
}
```

Xml-serialization works well. It is already in use. I suppose smth wrong with my WCF-configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by "the root element" is missing? What are you expecting to see? You are implementing IXmlSerializable so you are in control of the serialization

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply! I expect serialized string would contains root element either

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><protocol xmlns="http://schemas.aaa.ru/protocol-v3.0"><header version="3.0" language="Russian" /><references /></protocol>

Comment: can you show your IXmlSerializable iplementation?

Comment: SOAP wrapps serialized string into GetReferenceDataResult and GetReferenceDataResponse and root-element is missing. So serialozer could not deserialize it. Is there any why to prevent it?

Comment: you are providing the serialization for that data (you say you are implementing IXmlSerializable) - if you want a root element then supply one in your serialization routine

Comment: You have *explicitly* told the serializer to defer to you for the serialization of that object by implementing IXmlSerializable so what happens is entirely up to you

Comment: I've added serialization impl into main post, but I suppose smth wrong with my WCF-configuration.

Comment: I've tried to wrap ProtocolDocument into ProtocolDocumentWrapper in return value. Now there is root element in SOAP body. But it could not  be deserialized all the same. I could not understand anything!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have explicitly told it to ignore your root element in your WriteXml method - that's would be why there is no root element

```
var xmlSerializationFlags = XmlSerializationFlags.All & ~XmlSerializationFlags.IncludeRootElement;
```

If you cannot get deserialization to work you can always work at the XML level by using Message as the return type in your client's contract and then call GetReaderAtBody on the message, load the data into XElement and use LINQ to XML to transform the XML into objects to work with at the client side

Comment: Sorry, but this serialization is already used in http-requests and i'm not able to change it. Should i forget about SOAP so?